# Possible with Android to write custom dialer/in-call app to completely replace native Phone app?

Tags: android

Can I write a custom Phone app (dialer/in-call screen, etc.) with all the functionality of a native Android phone app?  I've read that certain functions, like conference calling, may be off-limits to third party developers, but I haven't yet found anything official regarding what may or may not be allowed.

Comment: it is possible, however in the background you will still use the call service provided by android

Comment: That's fine.  Any idea where I can find the documentation for accessing call recording (where available), conference calling, etc.?  I haven't been able to find it in the official Android documentation yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary) is the telephony API summary.

Also [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged) you can find a mini tutorial on how you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually found that before, and it's a great resource.  A very basic app I've already got (can dial and establish a call).  I was just wondering about the more specific, maybe more complicated features of a calling app.  I'll keep looking at the API documentation to see if I find anything.

Comment: Usually you won't find much more, most of that is built by someone and not a standard. You can search on github, that is the best chance to find anything useful, however there is a high chance that most of those projects will be outdated. One of those projects: https://github.com/Chooloo/call_manage

Comment: That project looks like it might be useful.  Just downloaded it and will poke through it tomorrow.  Thanks!